# Point `jdee-server-dir' to dir with JDEE jars issue

Tags: emacs, jdee

I am using Emacs with JDEE. When I want to compile the current Java file with C-c C-v C-c key binding, I encounter this message and don't compile:

> Point `jdee-server-dir' to dir with JDEE jars.

But I can run any Java file with C-c C-v C-r if it is compiled before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the [JDEE Server](https://github.com/jdee-emacs/jdee-server).  It works fine for me.